# Regex: Scrub HTML

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have a bunch of HTML code where I want to remove all the HTML markup.

I think this is possible with Regex (Regular expression). With search and replace, how would I do this?

I tried <*> where I thought * was a wildcard, but apparently not.
How would I make regex find all the 
< text > ?

Comment: Using notepadd++, but should work with any editor with regex and search-and-replace

Comment: What about the problem of e.g. &#8230 and &amp; etc. HTML character codes? No solution for that here. Oy vay, it would be nasty to convert all those with regexes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A simple version would be:

```
<[^>]+>
```

`[]` defines a character class, `^` excludes characters. Here is an [example](http://www.rubular.com/r/I8YzL4yY1a).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Select "Regular Expression" in Search Mode. Enter `[<].*?>` in Find What field and leave the Replace With field empty.